# Google Cloud Messaging library obsolete in Android studio

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android. I want to develop a Android app which sends push notifications on Android devices. I have code that imports packages like "com.google.android.gms.common" but I am unable to import these packages. Get confused about Google cloud messaging. Which packages shall I use to develop push notification app.

Comment: I would recommend learning through doing some tutorials, Google looks to have a good tutorial where you can download code, run it and it explains what it does: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you want to send push notifications to Android devices.

When using GCM on Android you want to use the gradle dependency:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0

[Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) is a simple project that only implements GCM.